# Badbox overfull with figures and tables in TexMaker

Tags: tables, floats, warnings

I have a lot of `badbox`type of error in my document. It doesn't seem to affect the layout but what does it means ? Should I resize my figures and tables ?

```
Overfull \hbox (6.77963pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 179--179
\T1/cmr/bx/n/10 A$[]$/A$[]$|
[]
Overfull \hbox (0.7736pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 179--180
[][]
[]
<img/ADN_total.png, id=31, 516.93124pt x 373.395pt>
File: img/ADN_total.png Graphic file (type png)
<use img/ADN_total.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: img/ADN_total.png used on input line 196.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 227.45044pt x 164.2943pt.
Overfull \hbox (0.602pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 196--197
[][]
[]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An overfull hbox (or horizontal box, in long version), occurs when the texing engine can't fit a box in the width of the page. Usually, it shows as text / drawing / equation going outside the right margin.

A good way to easily identify bad boxes is to use the `draft` option of most document classes, which prints a black box to the right of every overful box.

You can then check if it really doesn't affect the layout (pay attention to the space above and below the bad box as well). If it doesn't, or if you find the result acceptable, there is no reason you should resize anything. Bad boxes are only warnings.

### Example :

[image: Bad box]

(The black box is the result of the `draft` option of the `article` document class)

Comment: I see now, some of my figure are slightly wider than they should but it's not visible without the draft option.

Comment: If it's not visible (for example if it is white space in the figure) and if it doesn't cause poor spacing above or below the figure (see the space above my equation for an example), you can safely ignore it. :)